# Смена значений в input при клике

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Всем привет! Такая задача: нужно, чтобы при клике на кнопку изменялись значения в полях ( такое есть в гугл переводчике, например), но не знаю как реализовать, подскажите пожалуйста. 
Пример прилагаю: https://jsfiddle.net/r1zc3da2/10/
HTML:

```
<div><input value="Российский рубль" disabled="disabled"></div>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Сколько меняем?"></div>
<div class="swap"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt=""></div>
<div><input value="USD" disabled="disabled"></div>
<div><input type="text" placeholder="Вы получите: 0,25"></div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.swap {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}
.swap img {
  height: 8%;
  width: 8%;
}
```

Comment: `$('selector_button').click(function (e) { $('selector_input').val("new text"); });`. Вроде ничего сложного, в интернете полно примеров. Явно вопрос не для SO

Comment: нужно, чтобы эти значения менялись местами друг с другом http://prntscr.com/kpgojg

Comment: И в чём сложность? Что у вас не получилось. Приведите в вопросе js код. Ещё лучше - сделайте фрагмент кода.

Comment: сложность в том, что я особо не знаю js и не знаю как это загуглить правильно

Comment: Никто не знает js. Но в интернете полно ресурсов с учебными материалами. Дерзайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример

```js
document.onclick = function() {
var elem = window.event.srcElement;

if (elem.className == "butt") {
 var n1 = document.getElementById('n1').value,
     n2 = document.getElementById('n2').value;

 document.getElementById('n1').value = n2;
 document.getElementById('n2').value = n1;
}
};
```

```html
<input id="n1" value="1"><br>
<input id="n2" value="2"><br>

<button class="butt">Reverse</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! То, что нужно!

Comment: если вместо поля для ввода селект, как в этом случае быть?

Comment: [Пример](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUUKM0W54JQ2) :)